# Testing a static method that returns an instance

Tags: java, static

I wrote a class that has all static methods. There's one main static method used to return an instance, and then other helper static methods. I realize now that it's impossible to test this without using PowerMock, which I want to avoid. What would be the best way to refactor this class to make it testable?

```
public class MyClass {
    private final String str1;
    private final String str2;
    private final String str3;

    private MyClass(String str1, String st2, String str3) {
         this.str1 = str1;
         this.str2 = str2;
         this.str2 = str3;
    }

   public static MyClass getMyClassInstance() {
       str1 = staticHelperMethod("str1");
       str2 = staticHelperMethod("str2");
       str3 = staticHelperMethod("str3");

       if (str1 == null) {
            str1 = otherStaticHelperMethod("default");
       }

       if (str2 == null) {
           str2 = otherStaticHelperMethod("default");
       }

       if (str3 == null) {
           str3 = otherStaticHelperMethod("default");
       }
       
       return new MyClass(str1, str2, str3);
   }

    private static String staticHelperMethod(String str) {
        return System.getEnv(str);
    }

    private static String otherStaticHelperMethod(String str) {
        return "DEFAULT";
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't compile - there are methods declared without a return type.  But even without that, there seems be no point in having an instance at all, since there's nothing you can do with it: there are no non-static methods and no methods taking a MyClass argument.

Comment: Doesn't look like your class _should_ be mocked.  Looks testable to me.

Comment: @iggy Sorry I should have provided more context. Right now, the instance is only used to be passed as a parameter when instantiating another class. I'm starting to realize that I should just put these static methods in the other class, since that's the only time they get used.

Comment: @LouisWasserman how would this class be testable? There's 2 private static methods and 1 static method. I would need to stub the calls to staticHelperMethod and otherStaticHelperMethod to make getMyClassInstance testable, or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: The use of `System.getEnv` is problematic, but everything else looks fine.  If they don't depend on outside state, you _shouldn't_ stub those calls; this looks like a standard value object with helper methods that you should just make real instances of instead of mocking.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm not following; are you suggesting to make the helper methods instance methods instead of static methods like they currently are? I can't do that since the getMyClassInstance method is static.

Comment: No.  Leave them static.  If they're not dependent on outside state, then you don't need to touch them, stub them, change them, do anything with them.

Comment: @LouisWasserman then the class would not be testable without Powermock. I do not want to use Powermock, and want to find a way to test this class. Right now it is untestable.